# React-Dnd: Dynamic DropTarget and DragSource type

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I'm building a multi-level nestable drag and drop list. Each nested list needs to allow dragging only within itself. This requires setting a run-time `type` for the `DragSource` and `DropTarget`.

**Compile time `type` declaration works but is limited**

```
export default flow(
  DropTarget(ItemLevel.ROOT, target, connect => ({
    connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget(),
  })),
  DragSource(ItemLevel.ROOT, source, (connect, monitor) => ({
    connectDragSource: connect.dragSource(),
    isDragging: monitor.isDragging(),
  })),
)(MenuItem)
```

**Runtime `type` declaration seems to work but throws errors on dragging**

```
export const getGroupMenuItem = menuGroupId => flow(
  DropTarget(menuGroupId, target, connect => ({
    connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget(),
  })),
  DragSource(menuGroupId, source, (connect, monitor) => ({
    connectDragSource: connect.dragSource(),
    isDragging: monitor.isDragging(),
  })),
)(MenuItem)
```

[image]

Comment: what are those erros?

Comment: I've added a screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to react-dnd document, the type could be `a function which is given component's props. This drop target will only react to the items produced by the drag sources of the specified type or types.`